# Extract keys from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have

```
mylist = [{'age': 0, 'name': 'A'}, {'age': 1, 'name': 'B'}, {'age': 2, 'name': 'C'}, {'age': 3, 'name': 'D'}, {'age': 4, 'name': 'E'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'F'}]
```

How do I get

```
[{0:'A'},{1:'B'},{2:'C'},{3:'D'},{4:'E'},{5:'F'}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very elegant solution using a list comprehension.

```
>>> [{x['age'] : x['name']} for x in mylist]
[{0: 'A'}, {1: 'B'}, {2: 'C'}, {3: 'D'}, {4: 'E'}, {5: 'F'}]
```

Comment: @AaronMazie but your question indicated they were sets. Do you know the difference between {a, b} and {a : b}?

Comment: @AaronMazie You mean you want something like:

    {x['age']: x['name'] for x in mylist}

But age is not a good key since it's usually not unique, while name usually is, in which case you'll want:

    {x['age']: x['name'] for x in mylist}

Either way coldspeed indeed has the right answer given the exact question you asked.